# scala build a dictionary from a list and a function

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a scala list and a funcion:

```
val l = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

def f(x:Int, y:Int) = x+y
```

I want to build a dictionary that associated to each tuple its sum.

The result `f(1,2)` should be kept in memory and not recomputed each time that it is called. How can I do that? In python I would use a dictionary.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I want a sort of map such that m(x)=f(x0,x1) and with the result kept in memory in order to avoid to compute it again

Comment: Please explain with an example. Are you looking for `l map (items => items -> (f _).tupled(items))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analog to Python dictionaries in Scala is `Map`:

```
λ val resultsMap = Map(          // Create a map from a Seq of (key, value) pairs
                     l.zip(      // List(((1, 2), SOMETHING), ((3, 4), SOMETHING), etc.)
                       l.map((f _).tupled)  // Invoke `f` on each entry in `l`
                     ).toSeq : _*)
resultsMap: Map[(Int, Int), Int] = Map((1, 2) -> 3, (3, 4) -> 7, (5, 6) -> 11)
```

Usage:

```
λ resultsMap((1, 2))
res0: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l.map(x => x -> (f _).tupled(x)).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension we can extract the tuple values as well as bind each tuple for constructing the associations, like this,

```
for ( t@(a,b) <- l ) yield t -> f(a,b)
```

Thus applying `toMap` on the collection from the comprehension we get the desired map. In this approach though we must declare as many items in the tuple as we wish to be applied to the function.